# Rails 4 and Carrierwave - Image will not update properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, dropzone.js

I've struggled implementing multiple upload with carrierwave. I've succeeded in doing that, but I have noticed that while other fields work properly, the images will not update. I can't change the image or delete previously uploaded ones.

I'm QUITE certain it has something to do with my controller, especially the **post_params** and **update**.

Here is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_posts, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :home]

    def home
    end

    def index
        if params[:category].blank?
            @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id  
            @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")


        end
    end

    def show
        @inquiries = Inquiry.where(post_id: @post).order("created_at DESC")
        @random_post = Post.where.not(id: @post).order("RANDOM()").first
        @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all

    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
        @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @post.save 
                params[:post_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                    @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:image => a)

                end
                format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            else 
                format.html { render action: 'new' }

            end
        end
    end

    def update
      if @post.update(post_params)
        params[:post_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                    @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:image => a)
        flash[:notice] = "Post successfully updated!"
        redirect_to @post
        end
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong...give it another shot!"
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def edit
    end



    def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    def upvote
        @post.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def downvote
        @post.downvote_by current_user
        redirect_to @post
    end

    private 
    def find_posts 
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :price, :description, :location, :category_name, :contact_number, post_attachments: [])
    end
end
```

My form:

```
.edit-container
    = simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone" } do |f| 
        .edit-form
            = f.input :title
            = f.input :location, disabled: true
            = f.input :price
            = f.input :description
            = f.input :contact_number, placeholder: "(999) 999-9999"
            = f.label "Category"
            = f.text_field :category_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Category.order(:name).map(&:name)}, placeholder: "Choose a category"
            = f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p|
                = p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[image][]"

            = f.button :submit
%script
    $('#post_location').val("#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}")
```

**Example:**

For an example of its behavior now, if I upload 3 images and attempt editting the post, I get this:

[image]

So even if I keep all the images blank, when I submit it's still there. If I want to only upload 1 image, it doesn't change.

I want it to prepopulate the images with previously uploaded images when I edit a post, and change it to the new image when I choose to do so.

**Bonus:**

If you're feeling extra helpful today, you can help me by walking me through implementing either Jquery File Uploads or Dropzone.js for my current form (and make it work with my controller). That would be great of you.

---

**UPDATE**

post_attachment_controller

```
class PostAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /post_attachments
  # GET /post_attachments.json
  def index
    @post_attachments = PostAttachment.all
  end

  # GET /post_attachments/1
  # GET /post_attachments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /post_attachments/new
  def new
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new
  end

  # GET /post_attachments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /post_attachments
  # POST /post_attachments.json
  def create
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new(post_attachment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post_attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /post_attachments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /post_attachments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post_attachment.update(post_attachment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment.post, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /post_attachments/1
  # DELETE /post_attachments/1.json
  def destroy
    @post_attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_attachments_url, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post_attachment
      @post_attachment = PostAttachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_attachment_params
      params.require(:post_attachment).permit(:post_id, :image)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your server log when you are uploading your image. Everything starting from the beginning of the action until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add `post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :image]` to your `post_params`:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :price, :description, :location, :category_name, :contact_number, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :image])
end
```

Comment: That didnt do anything. When I choose another image it just adds that img to the rest of them, doesn't update it

Comment: Try: `post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :image]`

Comment: Nothing. There's a post_attachments_controller as well, could you look at that

Comment: There could be problems with your jquery. Try without using the `class: "dropzone"` in yout form and adding: `post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :image]` in your post_params

Comment: I think you have to do those in your `post_attachment_controller.rb` s `update` method

Comment: Let's move this to chat, shall we? I'm not sure how so you'll have to invite me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87915/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-loi-huynh).